# touchesBegan not called after dismissing UIAlertView in Cocos2d v3

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

After showing and dismissing a UIAlertView in my CCScene touchBegan stops responding. CCButton still respond to touches and if I tap a CCButton after dismissing the UIAlertView touchBegan starts working again.

Here is touchBegan which doesn't register touches after the alert until I press a CCButton

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];

        NSLog(@"touchBegan");

}
```

create UIAlertView

```
- (void)showAlert {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name" message:@"Enter Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert setTag:1];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];

}
```

Alert is dismissed

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (alertView.tag == 1) {

        UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        player.name = textField.text;

    }
}
```

This type of thing seemed to work fine under cocos2d v2.x using ccTouchBegan. What am I missing?

Comment: Adding self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; to -(id)init fixed the problem.